# Make a feature program Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, retrofit

I want make a program, which has 3 feature packages, eg. Bronze Package, Silver Package, Gold Package. Every package has a feature product.

If I choose bronze package, I want to get only the feature product inside bronze package etc.

How a make this in android studio?

```
  mFabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (setFabButtonStarColor() == R.color.colorWhiteFavoriteStar) {
                    mFabButton.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(DetailActivity.this, R.color.colorYellowFavoriteStar));
                    mFabButton.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.unsave_floatbutton));
                    try {
                        saveMovie();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    mFabButton.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(DetailActivity.this, R.color.colorWhiteFavoriteStar));
                    mFabButton.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.save_floatbutton));

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please change your image/GIF to sth that relates to your question. Please also look here to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think , it like productflavor.
If i choose silver package , i get a feature app for silver package.
And if i choose gold package, i get some feature app for gold package.

And then it just for one app.
for example, but i want to implement in product flavor

```
    int paketA, paketB, paketC;
paketA = 1;
paketB = 2;
paketC = 3;

int input = getInput() // ambil data dari inputan

if(input == paketA){
    showPaketA();
}else if(input == paketB){
    showPaketB();
}else if(input == paketC){
    showPaketC();
}else{
    showError(); // Handling untuk inputan yang tidak diketahui
}
```